# SQL display query results with specified columns appearing on the leftmost side of the table

Tags: jquery, sql

I need to display SQL query results by having specified columns appear first (on the leftmost side of the table).

The currrent code I have is:

```
Select * from table
order by column 4, column 3, column 1
```

Result:

```
column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4 - however it orders by the results in column 4 first.
```

The result I am looking for when using the same input is:

```
column 4, column 3, column 1, column 2
```

I do not care in which order the records are shown, I only care that column 4 appears first.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns explicitly instead of using `select *`. That always returns the columns in the order they appear in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
Select column4, column3, column1, column2
from table
order by column4, column3, column1
```

Comment: The table I am pulling from is very large, and therefore would be cumbersome to list out all columns. Additionally, I am trying to future proof the query in the likely case that data fields get added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

The ORDER BY clause is not referring to the order in which each column appears. Rather, it refers to the order of the values in the column itself. e.g. if you had an `ORDER BY height, weight` clause, then height would be ordered in ascending order, followed by weight. However, this would not affect which column would appear in the table first.

If you wanted to ensure that column 4 was first in the table, then it is simply a matter of designating it as such in the query, i.e:

`select column_4, column_3, column_2, column_1 from table;`

Comment: The table I am pulling from is very large, and therefore would be cumbersome to list out all columns. Additionally, I am trying to future proof the query in the likely case that data fields get added to the table.

Comment: In general you should avoid using `SELECT *` at all. Every query should just select the specific columns it needs. And the order doesn't usually matter -- that's handled by the user interface code, not the SQL.

Comment: If you really need to select all columns like this, the solution is to use dynamic SQL that gets all the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and reorders them according to whatever criteria you want.

Comment: @random: Do you need to list out all the columns per se? If the table is very large, then I am not sure why you would not simply pull out just those columns that are relevant - for performance issues if nothing else. In the case that more data fields get added to the table, then running a query could end up taking significantly more time.